# Select combination of numbers not in present table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns.
The table looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
7    12   15   24   39
10   11   27   30   36
1    10   15   22   32
3    18   19   20   40
6    16   21   24   31
```

I need to find all the combinations in the range between 1 and 40 not present in the current table.

How can I accomplish this task?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you don't mean EACH of the 5 columns has value from 1 to 40! This result would be 102 million rows minus your table's combinations! Is this reallyt what you want?

Comment: You can make a temp table with a single column containing rows with integers 1-40 and then do an `EXCEPT` to compare. `SELECT t1.f1, t2.f1, t3.f1, t4.f1, t5.f1 FROM temp t1, temp t2, temp t3, temp t4, temp t5 EXCEPT SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM yourtable;` But... this seems like a really strange requirement, with a HUGE number of permutations and a strange fit for SQL.

Comment: I smell a XY Question. What is the real problem you are trying to solve after you get this massive list of combinations?  Wouldn't this list be MORE than the current table?

Comment: "need to find all the combinations"   combinations of what?   what constitutes a "combination"?

Comment: Using your data, Would the result your're after be like the numbers 2,4,5,8,9,13,14...  So basically you're after finding all the numbers between 1-40 which are not present in cols 1-5?  which would mean at least 15 are missing given a 5x5 grid baring duplicates?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it will be more rows than the present table. What I really want is indeed, find every possible combination which is not already present in the table I have. Or, otherwise, search through existing table with the specific range of numbers. For example, if I want to search for the following numbers combinations 1, 5, 9, 23, 34, 22, 21 and 40, find all combinations not available in the existing table with this particular numbers.

Comment: Add an example and expected output given your current dataset.  I'm still not following what you're after.  What's confusing me is the word combinations.  so using your last comment.  5,9,23,34, would not be present and should show in the results? if so generating a temp table with the values you're looking for and left joining it to your base table unioning each column together should do the trick.

Comment: Should your result return a row with 1,1,1,1,1?

Comment: No, 1,1,1,1,1 is not a result I expect. Each number can repeat only once per row.

Comment: What about 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: @ZaurBakhramov Just out of curiosity - what is the end goal for this solution? There might be an easier way to go about it.

Comment: As an example, if I have 1000 rows, I want to find among specific numbers set all possible combinations not already present among those 1000 rows.

Comment: @Error_2646 My goal is to reduce combinations to selected numbers excluding those already present in the table.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis yes, this can be.

Comment: Sorry Zaur, I won't make a query for you that will return 40*39*38*37*36= 79 million combinations. Please note that what you ask is easy to do; I guess most people won't provide the answer to you in order to protect you.

Comment: @ZaurBakhramov But why? What's the over arching goal? I'm having a lot of difficulty imagining a problem which has this task as part of the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can make out, this is what is required: finding all combinations of 5 unrepeated numbers less than 40 that aren't in the existing list.

```
Create table [AllCombinations] (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int)

declare @loop1 int = 1
declare @loop2 int = 1
declare @loop3 int = 1
declare @loop4 int = 1
declare @loop5 int = 1

declare @topnum int = 40

while @loop1 <= @topnum
    begin
    set @loop2 = @loop1 + 1
    while @loop2 <= @topnum
        begin
        set @loop3 = @loop2 + 1
        while @loop3 <= @topnum
            begin
            set @loop4 = @loop3 + 1
            while @loop4 <= @topnum
                begin
                set @loop5 = @loop4 + 1
                while @loop5 <= @topnum
                    begin
                    Insert into [AllCombinations] values(@loop1, @loop2, @loop3, @loop4, @loop5) 
                    --print cast(@loop1 as char(2)) + ', ' + cast(@loop2 as char(2)) + ', ' + cast(@loop3 as char(2)) + ', ' + cast(@loop4 as char(2)) + ', ' + cast(@loop5 as char(2))
                    set @loop5 = @loop5 + 1
                    end
                set @loop4 = @loop4 + 1
                end
            set @loop3 = @loop3 + 1
            end
        set @loop2 = @loop2 + 1
        end
    set @loop1 = @loop1 + 1
    end

Create table [MyNumbers] (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int)
insert into [MyNumbers] values 
  (7 , 12, 15, 24, 39)
, (10, 11, 27, 30, 36)
, (1 , 10, 15, 22, 32)
, (3 , 18, 19, 20, 40)
, (6 , 16, 21, 24, 31)

select * from AllCombinations
except
select * from mynumbers
```